# How to handle jQuery Validation errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that i'm validating with some required fields in it. i'm using the jquery.validate plugin to validate the form. below is the snippet:
Js:

```
    var validator = $("#accountCreateForm").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",

        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    }

});
$('#button').on("click", function(){
  $.wm.net.restRequest('/account/data',{
     //post the required data
  }).fail(function() {
    // do the error handling
  }).done(function() {
    //post data successfully
   });
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" >

<div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text"  name="firstname" /><br />
<div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
<div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
  <div style="margin-left:140px;"><button id="button" type="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button></div>

 </form>
```

With the above initialization of the validation plugin, the form does not validate, mainly because im not doing anything in the error handling function. I'm not sure how can i handle the validation at the error function :

```
}).fail(function() {
    // do the error handling
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason for you to create a click handler at all.  The plugin already captures the click and does all of the error handling automatically, that's the whole point, and gives you a ton of [customization options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).  What *exactly* are you trying to "handle" regarding errors?

Comment: Nothing is working here because you've attached the `.validate()` method to `#accountCreateForm`, but your form's `id` is `register-form`.  Otherwise, your code would be working:  http://jsfiddle.net/owz0wgok/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form name is 'register-form', but you are validating 'accountCreateForm'.

Here I tried this one with your form, this works for me:

```
var validator = $("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
           required: true,
           email: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    }

});

$('#button').on("click", function(){

    if($('#register-form').valid()) 
    {
        /*  Do your saving, etc stuffs here */
        $('#register-form').submit();

    }

});
```

Comment: Just in case..don't forget to include jquery validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: You know the plugin includes a [`submitHandler` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) that already does all that.

Comment: hanks@Sparky and @mpalencia and sorry for the form name confusion..i feel stupid now for my silly mistake..